# Is this an error in the Java documentation for the GregorianCalendar method roll()

Tags: java, date, calendar, gregorian-calendar

In the GregorianCalendar class there is a method:

public void roll(int field, int amount)

It is documented here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#roll%28int,%20int%29

There are two methods for adding and subtracting some period of time to a Calendar with a set date: add() and roll(). You use or the other depending on this situation. When you would use roll(), it gives an example:

> Consider a GregorianCalendar originally set to Sunday June 6, 1999.
>   Calling roll(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -1) sets the calendar to Tuesday
>   June 1, 1999.
>
> This is because the roll rule imposes an additional constraint: The
>   MONTH must not change when the WEEK_OF_MONTH is rolled. Taken together
>   with add rule 1, the resultant date must be between Tuesday June 1 and
>   Saturday June 5.
>
> According to add rule 2, the DAY_OF_WEEK, an invariant when changing
>   the WEEK_OF_MONTH, is set to Tuesday, the closest possible value to
>   Sunday (where Sunday is the first day of the week).

I was trying this out myself yesterday:

```
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.set(1999,5,6);
System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString());
```

This prints:
Sun Jun 06 18:15:30 BST 1999

So far so good.
Now to try the roll method:

```
cal.roll(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -1);
System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString());
```

This prints: 
Wed Jun 30 18:15:30 BST 1999
It rolls back the time 1 week but keeps the month the same.

*Not* as the documentation suggested it would:
Tue June 1, 1999.

Is this an error in the documentation or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are rolling back from the "first week" to "zeroth week", which then gets flipped around to "last week of the month".

Do your weeks start with Sunday (as the documentation says it does for their example)?

If they start on Monday you can get different results (because you are no longer in the second week of the month at the beginning).

Try setting to a "Sunday locale".

Comment: yes. I set the date to June 6th 1999 as in the example which was a Sunday. I performed the roll method they with the same argument they used and got a different result.

Comment: What is the first day of week in the locale you are using? If it is Monday, then June 6th is the last day of the first week. If it is Sunday (like in the example), then June 6th is in the first day of the second week.